# How to fix /etc/ folder on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, chmod

I was following a tutorial which had this command to create a launchd.conf file in /etc/

```
sudo echo "some command" > /etc/launchd.conf
```

But it wouldn't work, I got permission denied after entering my admin password.
It seemed like the permissions for the link were wrong, so I did `sudo chmod 755 /etc/`
But now I can't load a terminal, I get the error `The administrator has set your shell to an illegal value`

If I tried to `sudo` a command now I get

```
sudo: can't open /private/etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
Process *tramp/sudo root@localhost* exited abnormally with code 1
```

This is what the link /etc looks like, what should it look like, and how do I restore it?

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root           wheel          11 Jul 21  2011 etc -> private/etc
```

/private/etc ...

```
drw-r--r-- 111 root           wheel    3774 Mar 26 02:25 etc
```

edit: I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.3

Comment: Nice one. :-P Always a better idea to elevate your own privileges than to change the permissions of your core directories. The permission denied you were getting was likely due to another problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kyle Jones' answer will definitely work, but have you tried running a Permissions Repair from Disk Utility? That might do the trick....

Comment: This is not what Repair Permissions is for.

Comment: Are you sure? It did fix the problem

Comment: @WilliamJackson To my knowledge, it checks the filesystem's permissions against installed packages (perhaps from .pkg receipts). As /etc/ is a file installed with the core OS, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @NReilingh I should have done more research before I spouted off. I was wrong and you are correct. I trivially edited the answer so I would be able to remove my downvote.

Comment: I also discovered that (at least in 10.7) you can find out if a file or folder will be fixed with Repair Disk Permissions by running this command in Terminal: `pkgutil --file-info /etc`, replacing `/etc` with any location you want to check. Of course that is not much help when you can't load Terminal.

Comment: This is a very handy feature, I'm glad it is there to help after I shoot myself in the foot :)

Comment: What in the world is `Permissions Repair`??  I cannot find it.

Comment: @IgorG. Since this answer was written, Apple has removed permissions repair since it is no longer necessary, thanks to SIP. It was previously found in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 10):

Reboot your Mac, holding down `command-s` when you first hear the boot chime.  Keep holding it down until you start seeing text on the screen.  The system will boot into single user mode with a root shell.

```
mount -uw /
chmod a+x private/etc
```

will make /etc accessible again.  Type `exit` to the shell and the Mac will finish booting.

Comment: Don't you have to mount the fs first?

Comment: private/etc is on the root partition.

Comment: The root partition is mounted readonly in single-user mode.  You have to remount it for write access (`mount -uw /`) in order for the chmod command to work.

Comment: @Gordon Indeed.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited the answer to include the needed mount command.

Comment: Upvote for the solution but also wanted to add that, in my case, it was the root that had the wrong permissions. So `chmod a+x /` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: For google/posterity's sake.. This seems to have solved my issues with `sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied` (albeit without having to restart  )

Answer (score -1):

Permissions and ownership of `/etc` and `/private/etc` seem both correct to me; by the way, you forgot to also check `/private`, which could also have wrong permissions.

I had exactly the same issue and in my case the permissions of the root folder itself got corrupted. What people overlook is that `/` is in fact also a real, normal directory and just like every directory it has ownership and permissions. Ownership should be `root:wheel` and permission should be `755` (that's `rwxr-xr-x`).

The easiest way to restore both was starting `Script Editor` and then typing and running that script:

```
do shell script "/usr/sbin/chown root:wheel /" with administrator privileges
do shell script "/bin/chmod 755 /" with administrator privileges
```

You are prompted for amdin password and then `chown` and `chmod` come to the rescue. After that `sudo` was working again.

Comment: The permissions _aren't_ correct. `x` flag is needed to enter a folder.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev `755` sets the `X`-flag for all users, `755` means `rwxr-x-r-x`: http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/755 and of course everyone needs permission to access `/` as otherwise you have access to nothing (as all files/folders, all mounted drives, yes even all devices are subfolders of `/` and you don't have access to them without the `X` flag)