# How to repair /etc/sudoers on OSX High Sierra

Tags: macos, sudoers, ownership

### How I got here

I installed an SSD drive after backing up my data. I installed OSX Maverick (because my laptop is circa 2014), and then I started copying over my data from user-2 to user-1 (because my user after installation of the OS did not match the user of the same name that saved the data in the backed up data).

Then I started to repair the ownership of files but I did something really bad: I ran `sudo chmod -R user-1:staff` in `/etc` and changed the ownership of `/etc/sudoers`. And with the file ownership corrupted, you cannot change it back.

### What I've tried

I've done single user mode boot and found that the file system is mounted read-only.

I've booted in recovery mode and found that OSX [no longer offers "Repair Disk Permissions" in Disk Utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074537/etc-sudoers-is-world-writable-on-mac-os-x-mavericks).

I've booted in recovery mode and found that [I cannot restore a single file from my Time Machine backup](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/07/11/how-view-and-restore-specific-files-time-machine/) because recovery mode allows only paving over your machine with all your Time Machine datas.

I've tried to do an ordinary boot but that takes 30 minutes and though the progress bar says that it has completed, the OS never comes up again.

### The question

So, how do I

1. get a user prompt on a writable file system so that I can set the ownership on `/etc/sudoers` or
2. get to [Finder to repair ownership](https://astrails.com/blog/2009/09/29/how-to-fix-a-hosed-etc-sudoers-file-on-mac-osx)

and maybe be able to boot my laptop again?

Sadly, I cannot get on as root with [this exploit](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/11/28/root_access_bypass_macos_high_sierra/) because I cannot get a dialog prompt for login.

---

Later 2018-01-21

I came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/404747/how-to-fix-etc-folder-on-mac-os-x) and was able to `mount -uw / && chmod 0 /etc/sudoers` successfully, but I still cannot boot. It may be something else caused by the `chown -R`.

Later still: when I boot in verbose mode (Command-V), I get infinite scroll of error message "Process X crashed: opendirectoryd. Too many corpses being created." This looks fatal. I may have to reinstall the OS and my backup.

Answer (score 10):

There is a way out (thanks to https://astrails.com/blog/2009/09/29/how-to-fix-a-hosed-etc-sudoers-file-on-mac-osx):

- be logged from an account with admin rights
- in a Terminal, run `open etc/` to see that directory from the Finder
- select the file `sudoers`
- get its information (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
- click the `+` to add permissions
- grant your account with Read-Write rights
- `vi /etc/sudoers` and fix your mess
- `:w!` to save (as it is still "Readonly")
- then run `sudo visudo` to restore proper rights on this file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to revert the entire /etc hierarchy to its proper ownership. It's mostly root:wheel, but there are a few exceptions. You can fix it in single-user mode after remounting the root volume for write access:

```
mount -uw /
chown -R root:wheel /etc
chown -R root:_lp /etc/cups
chown _lp:admin /etc/cups/certs
chown root:admin /etc/cups/certs/*
chown root:operator /etc/dumpdates    # It's ok if this file doesn't exist
```

Note that the order of execution is important, since the later `chown`s override the earlier ones.

Comment: I sort of went down this route. I looked at a Mac that was running correctly and `grep -v wheel`, saw only `cups` directory, saw my laptop did not have `cups` and just did `chmod -R 0 /etc`. No joy. So now I am paving and reinstalling my Time Machine backup. Hoping for the best.

Comment: Actually, an in-place reinstall from Recovery should also work, and preserve your user data (though that might not be a benefit at this point). BTW, you missed fixing the group along with owner.

Answer (score 0):

So after banging my head for 2hrs and 100 different articles, I managed to brute my way through.

1. Use finder to change permissions of sudoers file. Right click>Get info>Sharing and Permissions.Change it for all parties including 'everyone' to read & write. Not sure if this step is necessary though.
2. Delete sudoers file from /etc/ using finder after making a copy of it.
3. Shift new sudoers file back to /etc/
4. Use this command to restore your sudoers file https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394943